# Pause Video when css visibility is none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slideshow of an array of videos. I would like to have them paused when their container is not visible. I have tried several things, including variations of visibility listeners and play/pause commands. I have not had any luck getting this to work.

*Here is my html:*

```
<div id="video" class="mySlides"><video class="video" autoplay loop><source src="icx.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="widescreen" class="mySlides">
<!--<div id="written"><video autoplay><source src="written.mp4" 
type="video/mp4"></video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
<div id="tbd"><video autoplay><source src="tbd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>-->
</div>

<div id="last" class="mySlides"><video id="player" class="video" autoplay >
<source src="refresh.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>
```

I was using a counter to loop through the array but I want the videos to start from the beginning so I am refreshing the page when refresh.mp4 ends and using the following to slide through them.

*Script.*

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display = "none"; 
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(carousel, 11000); 

}
```

Here is my current javascript attempt to pause the video. I am open to jquery selections also. Even if it did work (which it doesn't) It would only work for 1 element. I would need it to pause all the videos that are not visible.

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("player");

function handleVisibilityChange() {
if (document[hidden]) {
videoElement.pause();
} else {
videoElement.play();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was in the process of changing it myself when you did. I inadvertently selected java instead of javascript.

Comment: How about pausing ALL of the videos - anytime the carousel changes... and then just playing the cell that is actively shown?